# FlexJson deserialization with custom ObjectFactories

Tags: java, json, deserialization, flexjson

I am using FlexJson to support my entities with JSON.

But I do have some problems deserializing them, because I want a "short data amount" to reduce the data volume sent between backend and client.

Lets suggest we do have a Person class which references to an address:

```java
public class Person {

    private String firstname;

    private String surname;

    private Address address;

}
```

So what I now want is, to deserialize an Person object containing just the address id and loading the address via this id from the database.

```
{
     "firstname":"Michael",
     "surname":"Blomkvist",
     "addressid":"1"
}
```

Any suggestions how to tell this the JSONDeserializer?

I tried to add a use("addressid", new MyCustomAddressObjectFactory()) but it never gets called.

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!